# image not rendering using react and webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi there so I am not using the command create react app so i have built every thing from scratch and this is my webpack configuration:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },

  target: "web",
  devServer: {
    port: "3000",
    static: ["./public"],
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        use: ['file-loader','url-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

then I was trying to add images to my app using css background-image:url("") or even by importing the image than put it inside the src of an img tag and in both cases the image was not displayed to the screen.
this is what I did so far:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './LoginScreen.css';
import i from '../../Images/online_auction.jpg'

const LoginScreen = ()=>{
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <img src={i}/>
            <label>Sign In</label>
            <input />
        </div>
    )
}


export default LoginScreen;
```

```css
*,*::before,*::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.body{
    margin: 0
}

.container{
    background-image: url("../../Images/online_auction.jpg");
    height: 220vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I would be grateful if you give me a hand in this.

Comment: ```const LoginScreen = ()=>{
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <img src={require("../../Images/online_auction.jpg)/>
            <label>Sign In</label>
            <input />
        </div>
    )
}```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add bable script to your html file
   You can find it here:
   https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html
2. use image like this:

> <img src={require ("img path") />